# Apple's Problematic Provisioning Portal

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk

I have restarted this process about 4 times over the past 3 weeks. I have not succeeded in submitting my app to the store. Please help me! I just started over again tonight, I did it in this order:

1. Deleted everything referring to the IPhone in my Keychain,
2. Redownloaded the Distribution Certificate
3. Created a new app id called: com.myapp
4. Downloaded the Provision Profile and installed it into XCode.

Please note: I did not install an Entitlements.plist because I was told I didn't need one. Everything is looking good at this point.

1. Duplicated my "Release" Configuration and renamed "Distribution"
2. Under the Configuration of "Distribution", Code Signing Identity, I can see my Provision Profile it actually says: IPhone Distribution: My Name (for Application Identifiers: com.myapp)

So at this point at the bottom of the Project Info Window I see this:

```
The name (“common name”) of a valid code-signing certificate in a keychain within your keychain path.   A missing or invalid certificate will cause a build error.  [CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY]
```

So I realize I haven't altered my bundle name for my app, I change it to com.myapp, warning still doesn't go away. I tried adding in my prefix into the Bundle Identifier like this:

5JSF8843kJJ.com.myapp (for example)

But the error still doesn't go away!

After all this I try to Build and Run on my device anyway thinking it may go away. But I get this error:

The iPod “myIpod” doesn’t have the provisioning profile with which the application was signed.

Click “Install and Run” to install the provisioning profile “myprofile” on “myIpod” and continue running “myappname.app”.

Please Help! I need to get this to work!

Thank you for your time.

UPDATE: I have fully tested the app and I am ready to distribute, I am trying to get a successful Build so that I can zip up my .app file and submit it using Application Loader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run an app using the Distribution certificate or Distribution Build.

You shouldn't duplicate your Release Build until after you get it running and configured exactly as needed, except for the choice of code signing certificate.

Comment: Im sorry I should clarify, I have fully tested and I'm ready to distribute, I have tested the app on my Ipod Touch. At this point, I'm trying to make a successful build, zip it up and send it with Application Loader

Comment: Also, just to make sure, I have to Build and Run the App in order to locate the .app in the finder, zip it up, and send it via Application Loader right?

Comment: Just Build.  Don't Run.  You can use Spotlight to find your build/Distribution folder if you've somehow lost it.

Comment: Thank you, surprisingly you are correct, I don't know why I thought I had to run the app as well as build it when I zip it up, my app is finally awaiting review.